# How do I find shortcuts to text editor Scratch?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, code

Hi I would like to know how to change between the in-build terminal and text editor tabs without mouse in scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change between the editor tabs and the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

Comment: It works only if the Terminal is visible. I am also interested in shortkey for toggle the Terminal visibility state, is there any?

Answer (score 0):

Alt+{number} where {number} is the order of the tab. I guess it works for up to 9 tabs, as Alt+0 does nothing on my system.

Comment: These are hotkeys to change between editor tabs.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + t is what you need?